# need m4 macro to prepend margin to arbitrary text

Tags: m4

Assume I define a m4 macro FOOBAR which contains a paragraph of 
arbitrary text, which may contain comma characters.  Please
create a m4 macro to add left margin of say 5 spaces to the
expansion of FOOBAR text.

The problem is simple (just use patsubst w/the "^" regex) if the 
text does not contain any commas.  But I need to handle commas.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to try yourself and then show what you tried in a concise manner.  Solutions won't be given without effort.

Answer (score 0):

Needs polishing, but it's a start:

```
m4_divert(-1)

I changed the m4 quoting to use [<{}>]

m4_define(_spaces,[<{m4_format([<{%}>]$1[<{s}>],)}>])

m4_define(_indent,[<{m4_patsubst($1,[<{^}>],_spaces($2))}>])

m4_define(_Comma_and_Paren_Safe,[<{m4_patsubst([<{[<{Some. arbitrary text,with unbalanced parentheses like:
((()((((
and several commas ,,,, and a few, more , of those 
commas,,.
}>]}>],[<{,}>],[<{[<{,}>]}>])}>])


m4_divert(0)m4_dnl
_indent([<{_Comma_and_Paren_Safe}>],7)
```

Example run (_m42 is simple m4 wrapper script):

```
$ _m42 < ~/tmp/2v.STDIN.m4-margin.SatMay16.2052.190
       Some. arbitrary text,with unbalanced parentheses like:
       ((()((((
       and several commas ,,,, and a few, more , of those 
       commas,,.
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler than prior attempt: save to macro FOOBAR - arbitrary text
paragraph nested inside quadruple quote to protect commas, and
unbalanced parentheses:

```
m4_divert(-1)

m4_define(_spaces,[<{m4_format([<{%}>]$1[<{s}>],)}>])

m4_define(_indent,[<{m4_patsubst($1,[<{^}>],_spaces($2))}>])

--
Simpler than prior attempt: save arbitrary text paragraph nested inside
quadruple quote to protect commas, and unbalanced parentheses:

m4_define(FOOBAR,[<{[<{[<{[<{Some. arbitrary text,with unbalanced parentheses like:
((()((((
and several commas ,,,, and a few, more , of those
commas,,.
}>]}>] }>]}>])

m4_divert(0)m4_dnl
_indent(FOOBAR,15)
```

Example run:

```
$ _m42 < ~/tmp/2v.STDIN.m4-margin.SatMay16.2052.190
               Some. arbitrary text,with unbalanced parentheses like:
               ((()((((
               and several commas ,,,, and a few, more , of those
               commas,,.
```